# Angular hot observables with RxJS: Changes on array are not emitted to subscribers

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have a small task board like trello with tasks to be done, doing and done. All the tasks are stored on 3 separate arrays in one service called `TaskService`. To show the task and change task state I have implemented angular's `cdk` [drag n drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview).

My goal now is to subscribe to the the task arrays so when the array changes send the changes to an api. For now I'm just trying to `console.log` the events but I'm not understanding what's happening it seemly to work but I can't get the arrays updates.

This is my component controller:

```
doing: any[];

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTodoTasks();
    // this.getDoingTasks();
    this.getDoneTasks();

    const obs$ = this.taskService.getDoing();

    obs$.subscribe({
      next: (data: any[]) => {
        this.doing = data;
        console.log(data);
      },
    });
  }

  todo: any[];
  // doing: Subscriber<any[]>;
  done: any[];
  newTaskText: string = '';

  isModalShown: boolean = false;

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer == event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }

  newTask() {
    console.log(`Click Modal!`);
    this.isModalShown
      ? (this.isModalShown = false)
      : (this.isModalShown = true);
  }

  getTodoTasks() {
    this.taskService.getTodos().subscribe((data) => {
      this.todo = data;
      console.log(`Se ha añadido Tak a : Todo`);
    });
  }
```

This is my view:

```
<app-modal *ngIf="isModalShown" (close)="newTask()">
  <div class="modalContent">
    <textarea
      name=""
      id=""
      cols="30"
      rows="10"
      class="newTask"
      [(ngModel)]="newTaskText"
    ></textarea>
    <div class="modalButtons">
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Cancel"
        class="btn btn-secondary"
        (click)="cancelTask()"
      />
      <input type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveTask()" />
    </div>
  </div>
</app-modal>

<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <h2>TO DO</h2>
    <input type="button" value="Modal" (click)="newTask()" />
    <div
      class="tasks"
      cdkDropList
      #todoList="cdkDropList"
      [cdkDropListData]="todo"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doingList, doneList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    >
      <div class="task" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    class="list"
    cdkDropList
    #doingList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="doing"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList, todoList]"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  >
    <h2>DOING</h2>
    <div class="tasks">
      <div class="task" *ngFor="let item of doing" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div
    class="list"
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doingList, todoList]"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  >
    <h2>DONE</h2>
    <div class="tasks">
      <div class="task" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my service:

```
constructor() {}

  todo = ['task 1', 'task 2', 'task 3'];
  doing = [];
  done = [];

  getTodos(): Observable<any[]> {
    return of(this.todo);
  }

  getDoing(): Observable<any[]> {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      subscriber.next();
    })
  }

  getDone(): Observable<any[]> {
    return of(this.done);
  }
```

I've been doing some tries and I couldn't manage to get a console.log on my terminal when a new element is added to any of the array through the drag n drop.

Comment: Hi @jcobo1 instead of using `of`, I would suggest using a behaviorSubject to create your observable with the initial todos e.g `new BehaviorSubject(todo)`, then subscribe to the behaviorSubject in your component.

Comment: no difference when using BeahviourSubject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn’t find any solution so instead I added an `id` parameter to the drop areas so I can identify the drop area destination and then implement my logic.

If anyone finds out what’s missing in my code I’ll update the question with the right solution.